# ESRI Flex Viewer 2.4 - Changing Widget Title At Runtime

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, arcgis-flex-viewer

I have an "About" widget which displays information about the current active widget in my Flex Viewer app.  I am trying to update the About widget's title accordingly.  For example, if 'Super Fancy Widget' is active, the about widget title would read 'About Super Fancy Widget'.

Updating the widget title property only seems to stick the first time.  Continuing on my example above, if I then activate 'Other Widget', the about widget's title still shows 'About Super Fancy Widget'.

The snippet below is the code that I am expecting to update the widget's title.  It is in the About widget, and basically just sets the widgetTitle property from the WidgetTemplate.as

```
public function set aboutTitleLabel(value:String):void
{
     this.widgetTitle = value;
     this.invalidateProperties();
     this.invalidateDisplayList();
     this.validateNow();
}
```

Any ideas on how to change the title dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a post on the ESRI Flex API hwere I answered this question:

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/51780-Change-FlexViewer-widget-icon-and-label-programmatically

Comment: Nice, it helped. :)